# How to check if webclient got correct response C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, conditional-statements, webclient

got typical api request for sending sms through sms gateway.

Any chance that I can check connection of the device?

```
string readUrl = "http://192.168.253.160/index.php/http_api/read_sms";
        string result;

        WebClient Client = new WebClient();

        Client.QueryString.Add("login", "admin");
        Client.QueryString.Add("pass", "password");
        Client.QueryString.Add("folder", "sentitems");
        Client.QueryString.Add("idfrom", "100");
        Client.QueryString.Add("idto", "101");
        Client.QueryString.Add("limit", "1");
        Client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");

        Stream receivedStream = Client.OpenRead(readUrl);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receivedStream);

        result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        receivedStream.Close();
        reader.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(result);
```

I would like to make condition:

```
if(result == true)
 {
   button green
 }
else
 {
   button Red
 }
```

I know that if i check folder sentitems with correct ID and I get correct result I will get response what can I use in this condition. But this response is so long. So I am just thinking about another/different option.

Thanks

Comment: *Don't* use WebClient if you target any supported .NET version (4.5.2+). Use HttpClient with [GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551729(v=vs.118).aspx) and check the response status before you decide how to proceed. Eg `var response=await client.GetAsync(...,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){ var body=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ...}`

Comment: The [documentation of the HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) class shows how to use it, reuse it in multithreaded scenarios etc

Comment: Ping has nothing to do with HTTP. Are you asking how to check whether a site is up? The code in the comments does that already - `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` means you'll get a response as soon as the response headers are received. In the 200 case you can ignore the rest of the response.

Comment: If you want to send a HEAD, you can do that with `SendAsync` and an HttpRequestMessage with its method set to HttpMethod.Head